# How to read 2 Kafka topics sequentially in one consumer class using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 2 Kafka topics A and B. I want that every time when my consumer starts up, it goes to topic A first. Topic A contains information about topic B, and I'll depend on that information to fetch data from topic B.

So essentially I need to read topic A first before going to topic B, and I just need to do this once upon every restart of my program.

Things I can think of like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"A" , "B"})
```

Or:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "A")
public void receive() {}

@KafkaListener(topics = "B")
public void receive() {}
```

Both don't guarantee the sequence of reading.

How can I enforce my program to read topic A first, and only go to topic B after finishing the latest updates on topic A?

Comment: For people who kept voting this question as not "focused", can you show me how i should divide it into multiple sub-qns to satisfy your criteria? Or what are the different qns you think it contains?
i mean, seriously, the subject line and the last sentence of the description are not the same, but it doesn't mean it contains 2 questions right?

Comment: I didn't vote, but 'needs more focus' doesn't necessarily mean it is asking more than one question, it can also mean you're question is too broad (as in the solution could take a whole article or book). In any case, I think you can't solve this easily. Kafka topics are by their nature asynchronous, so there is no real order. If you want order, you probably need to use a pull-based mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Mark, got the solution from Russell below. It is not an essay-like answer, and it's exactly what i need. That's why i feel people may be too hurry clicking "needs more focus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this...

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "bReceiver", autoStartup = "false, topics = "B")
public void receive() {}
```

Set the `idleEventInterval` and add

```java
@Autowired
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

@EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId == 'aReceiver`)
public void eventListener(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    this.registry.getListenerContainer("aReceiver").stop(() -> { });
    this.registry.getListenerContainer("bReceiver").start();
}
```

Comment: Hi Russell, while attempting this approach I hit some new issue can you kindly help to take a look? Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091106